# canvas performance drop after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wrote the following 1000 bounding squares demo as a test of the capabilities of HTML5 canvas. It runs fine at first but then a noticeable drop in fps after a few seconds. I am not sure why. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = c.getContext("2d");

var WIDTH = 600;
var HEIGHT = 800;

c.width = WIDTH;
c.height = HEIGHT;

image = loadImage("square.png");

function loadImage(imageName){
    var i = new Image();
    i.src = imageName;
    return i;
}


function clear(){
    context.fillStyle = "#d0e7f9";
    context.rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    context.fill();
}
clear();

var SpriteList = [];

var Sprite = (function() { //javascript class(?)... shredders
    function Sprite(){  //constructor
        this.x = Math.random()*WIDTH;
        this.y = Math.random()*HEIGHT;
        this.vx = Math.random()*10;
        this.vy = Math.random()*10;
        SpriteList.push(this);
    }

    Sprite.prototype.update = function(){
        this.x += this.vx;
        this.y += this.vy;

        if (this.x<0 || this.x>WIDTH){
            this.vx *= -1;
        }
        if (this.y<0 || this.y>HEIGHT){
            this.vy *= -1;
        }
    };

    return Sprite;
})();

for (var i = 0;i<1000;i++){
    new Sprite();
}

function draw(){
    clear();
    for (i in SpriteList)
    {
        var s = SpriteList[i];
        s.update();
        context.drawImage(image, s.x, s.y);
    }
}

setInterval(draw,1000/60);
```

Comment: Not that this will fix your problem, but `image` should be `var image` and `for(i in SpriteList)` should be `for(var i in SpriteList)`. Declare all your variables.

Comment: You should separate your draw and update logic. The problem is as markE points out is that they are overlapping each other so to speak. Requests to update the positions of the images should not coincide with requests to draw them, otherwise it will cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code but the main reason for this to happen is this code:

This code will require you to use `beginPath()`:

```
function clear(){
    context.fillStyle = "#d0e7f9";
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT); /// this will require beginPath();
    context.fill();
}
```

or to avoid it, you can simply modify the code to do this:

```
function clear(){
    context.fillStyle = "#d0e7f9";
    context.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT); /// this does not require beginPath();
}
```

**[Live fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/trSe4/)**

```
/// use a var here    
var image = loadImage("square.png");

/// your image loader is missing - image may not show up
function loadImage(imageName){
    var i = new Image();
    i.onload = nextStep; /// something like this
    i.src = imageName;
    return i;
}

var SpriteList = [];

/// create this as an object
function Sprite(){  //constructor
    this.x = Math.random()*WIDTH;
    this.y = Math.random()*HEIGHT;
    this.vx = Math.random()*10;
    this.vy = Math.random()*10;
    return this;
}

Sprite.prototype.update = function(){
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;

    if (this.x<0 || this.x>WIDTH){
        this.vx *= -1;
    }
    if (this.y<0 || this.y>HEIGHT){
        this.vy *= -1;
    }
};

/// separate pushing of the instances
for (var i = 0;i<1000;i++){
    SpriteList.push(new Sprite());
}

var oldTime = 0;

function draw(timeElapsed){ /// in milliseconds
    clear();

    var diffTime = timeElapsed - oldTime;

    /// use vars here too
    for (var i = 0, s; s = SpriteList[i]; i++ )
    {
        s.update();
        context.drawImage(image, s.x, s.y);
    }

    oldTime = timeElapsed;

    /// use rAF here
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw(0); /// start
```

The `setInterval` may cause the whole thing to stack calls if the browser is not fast enough processing the sprites within the time budget you give,.

By using rAF the browser will only request a frame when it can even if that means lower frame rates - you will at least not lock up/slow down the browser.

(as you didn't provide a link to the image you're using I substituted it with a temp canvas - you will still need to consider a `onload` event handler for the actual image).

Comment: Is there a way to get dt from requestAniatmionFrame?

Comment: Time between each draw() call. Usually used to fix the timestep, ie, rather than `x += vx`; its better done as `x += vx * dt`;.

Comment: @NoHarmInTrying updated answer. The argument can now be used for time (to get the difference just store the current as old time at the end of function and subtract it when you have the new time). This is more accurate than using the Date object.

Comment: @NoHarmInTrying if you see the fiddle the time elapsed per frame and in total is printed in the corner.

Comment: On the fiddle it still slows down on my end. The squares moves noticeably slower compared to when first ran.

Comment: @NoHarmInTrying which browser do you use?

Comment: Tried it on Chrome and Firefox the result is the same. The timeElapsed start at ~17 then goes up to ~60 which means the update() are called less frequently and thus the squares move slower. What I don't get is why is the timeElapsed is increasing over time.

Comment: @NoHarmInTrying ok, found the error. I didn't study your clear() function close enough (I thought of it as clearRect)  and in there you are using a rect() call which will accumulate. This will require beginPath() or simply use fillRect() instead. See updated answer + fiddle

Comment: Alright thanks! that fixed it. I copied the code from an example somewhere and I didnt realize its performance penalties.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

Use image.onload to be sure your square.png is fully loaded before it's used.

Put the image loading at the bottom of your code after you create your 1000 sprites.

```
var image=new Image();
image.onload=function(){
    draw();
}
image.src="square.png";
```

Don't iterate using for(i in SpriteList).  Do this instead:

```
for(var i=0;i<SpriteList.length;i++)
```

Your draw functions are probably stacking--the current draw() isn't being completed before setInterval is requesting another draw().

Replace setInterval with requestAnimationFrame to stop your stacking problems.

```
function draw(){

    // request another animation frame
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    // draw the current frame
    clear();
    for(var i=0;i<SpriteList.length;i++)
    {
        var s = SpriteList[i];
        s.update();
        context.drawImage(image, s.x, s.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it important to declare all the vars? Is `var x = 0;` not the same as `x = 0;`? It seems to work. Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question - I have been working with JavaScript for less than 24 hrs.

Comment: Using "var" limits the visibility of the variable to the current scope (the current function or the current script file).  Not using "var" will let the variable leak into global scope (available to all scripts on the page).  Maintaining proper scope boundaries becomes more important as you begin to combine multiple scripts.  For example, if you declare a "non-var'ed" image variable here it will (unfortunately) be visible in every other script on your webpage.  Your square.png could unexpectedly be used as your company logo! Also, global vars take longer to fetch so var is performance friendly.

Comment: Gotcha. So basically it is treated as a global without explicitly declaring it to be a var? That is certainly an interesting feature.